# How do I compare lines in two files WITHOUT respect to their position in those files (set difference operation)

Tags: bash, set

diff and similar tools seem to compare *files*, not *content* that happens to be in the form of lines in files. That is, they consider the position of each line in the file as significant and part of the comparison.

What about when you just don't care about position? I simply want to compare two lists in more like a set operation *without* any respect to position. Here each line can be considered a list element. So, I'm looking for what is the *difference* between lines in file1 and file2, and file2 and file1.

I don't want to see positional information, or do any a pairwise compariosn, just a result set for each operation. For example:

```
SET1: a b c d f g

SET2: a b c e g h

SET1 - SET2 = d f

SET2 - SET1 = e g
```

Can I do this easily in bash? Obviously it's fine to sort the list first or not but sorting is not intrinsically a prerequisute to working with sets

Comment: `diff <(sort file1) <(sort file2)`?

Comment: https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/036

Comment: Don't just show the most trivial, sunniest-day case where each file has a unique set of characters unless that's all you really care about. Show cases whee the input is multi-char strings with some strings being substrings of others across files, some containing regexp metachars, some lines with multiple words, some duplicated within a file, etc. Otherwise you'll get answers that work for the inputs you show but fail later for various other inputs.

Comment: You say `I simply want to compare` - what kind of comparison? string or regexp? full-line or full-word or partial-line or partial-word? Presence or matches or exact counts of matches? Something else?

Comment: exact matches, excluding leading/trailing spaces and non-printing characters

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For simple line-oriented comparisons, the [`comm` command](https://linux.die.net/man/1/comm) might be all you need:

```
$ tail a.txt b.txt 
==> a.txt <==
a
b
c
d
f
g

==> b.txt <==
a
b
c
e
g
h
```

```
$ comm -23 <(sort a.txt) <(sort b.txt)
d
f
```

```
$ comm -13 <(sort a.txt) <(sort b.txt)
e
h
```

Also, it's probably worth it to enable the `--unique` flag on `sort` in order to remove duplicate lines:

```
comm -23 <(sort --unique a.txt) <(sort --unique b.txt)
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you want to do full-line string comparisons and consider counts of lines rather than just appearances of lines as differences, this might do what you want (untested):

```
awk '
    NR==FNR {
        set1[$0]++
        next
    }
    $0 in set1 {
        both[$0]++
        if ( --set1[$0] == 0 ) {
            delete set1[$0]
        }
        next
    }
    {
        set2[$0]++
    }
    END {
        for ( str in both ) {
            printf "Both: %s (%d)\n", str, both[str]
        }
        for ( str in set1 ) {
            printf "Set1: %s (%d)\n", str, set1[str]
        }
        for ( str in set2 ) {
            printf "Set2: %s (%d)\n", str, set2[str]
        }
    }
' file1 file2
```

Answer (score 0):

If your fields are all separated by spaces, you may use a four steps process:

- split
- sort
- compare
- aggregate

```
tr " " "\n" file1 | sort > file1.tmp
tr " " "\n" file2 | sort > file2.tmp
diff file1.tmp file2.tmp | tee /tmp/result
```

and now, aggregate the results:

```
echo "file1: $(diff file1.tmp file2.tmp | egrep "^>" | sed 's/^> //' | tr "\n" " " )"
echo "file2: $(diff file1.tmp file2.tmp | egrep "^<" | sed 's/^< //' | tr "\n" " " )"
rm /tmp/result file1.tmp file2.tmp
```

Eventually, to match exactly your field format, append a `| tr -s " "` to your two echoes.

Comment: Absolutely!
```egrep "^>" ``` and ```egrep "^<"``` instead of ```grep ">"```, and replace the ```tr -d``` by ```cut -d -f 1```

Comment: and even, replace ```cut -d\> -f2``` by sed, to trim leading space.

Comment: No fields. Stackoverflow removes new lines unless they are double spaced so it's represented here as elements separated by spaces, but the question is about each element being on it's own line.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this works, but `comm -23` is much nicer

```
#!/bin/bash
LINESX=$(cat $1)
LINESY=$(cat $2)
for LINEX in $LINESX
do
    for LINEY in $LINESY
    do
        if [ "$LINEX" = "$LINEY" ]
        then
            match=1
            break
        fi
    done

  # For intersection
  #if [ $match -eq 1 ]
  #then
  #    echo "$LINEX"
  #fi

  # For difference
  if [ $match -eq 0 ]
  then
      echo "$LINEX"
  fi
done
```